# judge which phrase the clause refer to

Tags: syntax

I read the sentence

> The driver **process** runs your main() 
>    **function**, sits on a node in the cluster, and is responsible for
>   three things:...

I am not sure

> sits on a node in the cluster

*modify* the *process* or *function* . I always stumble by the similar situation, please tell me how I can call this syntax and what's the rule to judge this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to look for a relative pronoun such as **which**.

We are comparing these two patterns

> The X is a, b, and c
>
> The X is a, which b

In your example you are asking how we know that "sits ..." tells us more about **process** rather than **your main function**.

In technical terminology you are asking how we can identify a **non-restrictive relative clause**. The two identifiers are

1. a preceding comma
2. the use of **which** (or other relative pronouns such as who)

> The driver process runs your main() function, sits on a node in the cluster

No which, so we are learning more about the driver process

> The driver process runs your main() function, which you have developed

Here we have a **which**. So this is a non-restrictive relative clause, which gives us more information about the main() function.

For comparison, there is also the possibility of a **restrictive** relative clause. This has no preceding comma and often uses **that**. A restrictive clause is essential to the meaning of the sentence.

> Rugby is a game that is played with an oval ball.

There are some differences between US and UK uses of **that** and **which** and you can read more about this in articles such as [this one](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/09/07/that-who-which/).

Comment: I am confused by  two identifiers in your description, The two  identifiers  means  non-restrictive relative clause. My example apply identifier 1, your example apply identifier  2, but why have different meaning?

Comment: My example applies **both** identifiers: the comma **and** the "which". Your example does not have "which", so it is not a "non-restrictive relative clause". It's the **which**:  "The X is a, which b" is the pattern that links b to a, not to X.

Comment: thanks, so your two identifiers  are "and" relation to constitute "non-restrictive relative clause"? I thought wrong as "or" relation.

Comment: BTW,could you tell me my original sentence's technical terminology?

Comment: Yes **and** not **or**. I'm not confident of the terminology, but I think you have a sequence of non-restrictive clauses. You could remove either "runs your main() function" or "sits on a node in the cluster" and the sentence would be well formed and understandable; though it would lose information it is still grammatically correct.